Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Class constructor MsalGuard cannot be invoked without 'new'
I am using Microsoft Login in my Angular application and below is my version of Angular and Node.JS installed
Angular CLI: 16.2.14
Node: 18.17.1
I have created a module name "Home" in which all the other modules are imported and I have imported Home Module in my App Module. So I have written the MSAL Configuration Code in Home.Module.TS as below:
const isIE = window.navigator.userAgent.indexOf('MSIE ') > -1 || window.navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Trident/') > -1;
export function loggerCallback(logLevel: LogLevel, message: string) {

  console.log(message);

}

export function MSALInstanceFactory(): IPublicClientApplication {

  return new PublicClientApplication({

    auth: {
      clientId: '551eb551-c9b8-423c-976e-fa795755b5df',    //localhost env

        authority:'https://login.microsoftonline.com/04ea39e3-ac5b-4971-937c-8344c97a4509/',

       redirectUri:'http://localhost:4200/'
           },

    cache: {

      cacheLocation: BrowserCacheLocation.SessionStorage,

      storeAuthStateInCookie: isIE, // set to true for IE 11. Remove this line to use Angular Universal

    },

    system: {

      loggerOptions: {

        loggerCallback,

        logLevel: LogLevel.Info,

        piiLoggingEnabled: false

      }

    }

  });

}



export function MSALInterceptorConfigFactory(): MsalInterceptorConfiguration {

  const protectedResourceMap = new Map<string, Array<string>>();

  protectedResourceMap.set('https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me', ['user.read']); // Prod environment. Uncomment to use.

  // protectedResourceMap.set('https://graph.microsoft-ppe.com/v1.0/me', ['user.read']);



  return {

    interactionType: InteractionType.Redirect,

    protectedResourceMap

  };

}



export function MSALGuardConfigFactory(): MsalGuardConfiguration {

  return {

    interactionType: InteractionType.Redirect,

    authRequest: {

      scopes: ['user.read']

    },

    // loginFailedRoute: '/login-failed'

  };

}

And In Home-Routing.Module.TS, I have written below line to route to Landing Component.
const routes: Routes = [

  { path: '', component: LandingComponentComponent, canActivate:[MsalGuard] },
];


And I have activated the MSAL Guard in LandingComponentComponent where after authenticating from Microsoft, user gets logged in.
Below is my Landing.Component.TS file :
  isIframe = false;
  loginDisplay = false;


  ngOnInit(): void {
    
       this.isIframe = window !== window.parent && !window.opener; // Remove this line to use Angular Universal

    this.setLoginDisplay();

    this.getProfile();

    this.msalBroadcastService.inProgress$

      .pipe(

        filter((status: InteractionStatus) => status === InteractionStatus.None),

        takeUntil(this._destroying$)

      )

      .subscribe(() => {

        this.setLoginDisplay();

        this.checkAndSetActiveAccount();

      })




    localStorage.setItem("isLandingPage", "false");
    this.httpService.post("getEmpList",{}).subscribe(
      data => {
        if (data.success) {
          let data_ = data.data;
          
          sessionStorage.setItem('UserList', JSON.stringify(data.data))
          this._sharedService.setEmployeeData(data_);
        } else {
          if(data.msg === "Invalid Session")
              {
                alert("Session has been expired!! Please login again");
              }
              else
              {
                alert("Could not get employee details. Error: " + data.msg);
              }
        }
      },
      error => {
        console.log(error);
        alert("Could not get employee details. ");
      }
    )
  }


  setLoginDisplay() {

    this.loginDisplay = this.authService.instance.getAllAccounts().length > 0;

  }


  checkAndSetActiveAccount() {

    /**
  
     * If no active account set but there are accounts signed in, sets first account to active account
  
     * To use active account set here, subscribe to inProgress$ first in your component
  
     * Note: Basic usage demonstrated. Your app may require more complicated account selection logic
  
     */

    let activeAccount = this.authService.instance.getActiveAccount();



    if (!activeAccount && this.authService.instance.getAllAccounts().length > 0) {

      let accounts = this.authService.instance.getAllAccounts();

      this.authService.instance.setActiveAccount(accounts[0]);



    }

    if (activeAccount) {
      this.activeuser = activeAccount.username;
      sessionStorage.setItem('username', this.activeuser)
    }
  }


  getProfile() {
    console.log("getprofile function");

    this.http.get('https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me').subscribe(res => {
      
      this.res2 = JSON.stringify(res)
      this.res3 = JSON.parse(this.res2)
      
    
      sessionStorage.setItem("empid", this.res3.extension_6d1109881ca84719973dbff443d7b820_employeeNumber)
      var empno = sessionStorage.getItem("empid")
      console.log("empno", empno);
      sessionStorage.setItem("emp_name", this.res3.displayName)
      sessionStorage.setItem("emp_desg", this.res3.jobTitle)
      sessionStorage.setItem("emp_emailid", this.res3.mail)
      var empname = sessionStorage.getItem("emp_name")
      var empdesg = sessionStorage.getItem("emp_desg")
      var empmail = sessionStorage.getItem("emp_emailid")
      console.log("empname emdesg empmail", empname, empdesg, empmail);

      this.httpService.post("login", {
        username: this.res3.extension_6d1109881ca84719973dbff443d7b820_employeeNumber
      }).subscribe(
        data => {
          if (data.success) {
            // if(data.data.emp_id){
            console.log("data", data);
            this._sharedService.setUserRole(data.data.menu[0].erole_id)
            
            localStorage.setItem("emp_role", data.data.menu[0].erole_id);
            this.role = Number(localStorage.getItem('emp_role'))
            if(this.role === 8 || this.role === 10 || this.role === 11 ){
              this.role_flag = true
            }else{
              this.role_flag = false
            }
            localStorage.setItem("isLoggedIn", "true");
            localStorage.setItem("isLandingPage", "true");
            localStorage.setItem("emp_id", this.res3.extension_6d1109881ca84719973dbff443d7b820_employeeNumber);
            localStorage.setItem("emp_name", this.res3.displayName);
            localStorage.setItem("emp_desg", this.res3.jobTitle);
            localStorage.setItem("loginDetails", JSON.stringify(data.data));
            // }
            // this.router.navigate(['/home']);
          } else {
            if (data.msg === "Invalid Session") {
              alert("Session has been expired!! Please login again");
            }
            else {
              alert("No Role Detected !");
            }
          }

        },
        error => {
          console.log(error);
          alert("Error Occurred! Please try again...")
        }
      )
    })

   

  }


  login() {

    this.authService.loginPopup()

      .subscribe({

        next: (result) => {

          // console.log(result);

          this.setLoginDisplay();

        },

        error: (error) => console.log(error)

      });

  }

  loginRedirect() {

    if (this.msalGuardConfig.authRequest) {

      this.authService.loginRedirect({ ...this.msalGuardConfig.authRequest } as RedirectRequest);

    } else {

      this.authService.loginRedirect();

    }

  }

  loginPopup() {

    if (this.msalGuardConfig.authRequest) {

      this.authService.loginPopup({ ...this.msalGuardConfig.authRequest } as PopupRequest)

        .subscribe((response: AuthenticationResult) => {

          this.authService.instance.setActiveAccount(response.account);
          // console.log('.......................>', response.account)

        });

    } else {

      this.authService.loginPopup()

        .subscribe((response: AuthenticationResult) => {

          this.authService.instance.setActiveAccount(response.account);


        });

    }

  }

  logout(popup?: boolean) {

    if (popup) {

      this.authService.logoutPopup({

        mainWindowRedirectUri: "/"

      });

    } else {

      this.authService.logoutRedirect();

    }

  }


  ngOnDestroy(): void {

    this._destroying$.next(undefined);

    this._destroying$.complete();

  }
  showWelcomeMessage() {

    this.authService.instance.getActiveAccount + " to Microsoft Graph API";

  }

}

I tried "ng serve" in my VSCODE terminal and in the browser, I got a blank screen with an error message in Console Tab as:
Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Class constructor MsalGuard cannot be invoked without 'new'
TypeError: Class constructor MsalGuard cannot be invoked without 'new'
    at router.mjs:3339:52
    at R3Injector.runInContext (core.mjs:9276:20)
    at router.mjs:3339:33
    at Observable._subscribe (defer.js:5:19)
    at Observable._trySubscribe (Observable.js:37:25)
    at Observable.js:31:30
    at errorContext (errorContext.js:19:9)
    at Observable.subscribe (Observable.js:22:21)
    at take.js:10:20
    at OperatorSubscriber.<anonymous> (lift.js:10:28)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:1193:31)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:1147:17)
    at zone.js:1260:17
    at _ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:402:31)
    at core.mjs:10757:55
    at AsyncStackTaggingZoneSpec.onInvokeTask (core.mjs:10757:36)
    at _ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:401:60)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.mjs:11070:33)
    at _ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:401:60)
    at Zone.runTask (zone.js:173:47)

I am not getting why this error is coming ?? Please help
